# Query 2 dimensional array using native php array functions

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sorting

I have converted a CSV to a two dimensional array where the following array structure stores the column and row data

```
$table['status'] = ['active', 'active', 'inactive'];
$table['plan']   = ['annual', 'weekly', 'weekly  '];
$table['spend']  = ['12,000', '19,000', '0'       ];

print_r($table);
```

would appear as follows:

```
( [status] => Array ( [0] => active [1] => active [2] => inactive ) 
  [plan] => Array ( [0] => annual [1] => weekly [2] => weekly ) 
  [spend] => Array ( [0] => 12,000 [1] => 19,000 [2] => 0 ) )
```

I want to use native PHP array functions to query the arrays without having to write loops with nested conditions. If this was a MySQL database and I wanted to find the sum of spend from accounts with active status and weekly plans I would simply run the following query

```
SELECT SUM('Spend') FROM table WHERE status = 'Active' AND plan = 'Weekly';
```

But instead I have to take the following approach using a for loop

```
for ($index = 1; $index < count($table); $index++){
    if (($table['status'][$index] == 'active') && ($table['plan'][$index] == 'weekly')){
        $spend[$index] = $table['spend'][$index];
    }
}

echo array_sum($spend);
```

This approach gives me a headache. Is there an obvious solution for refactoring this into php's native array functions or is a mess of explicit loops inevitable?

Comment: Does the csv data have to be in that in format? Could convert it to a list of rows: $table = array(array(active=>1, 'plan'=>'weekly', 'spend'=>12000), array(.... etc ) and then use array_filter to extract the ones you want.

Comment: I am considering that format. Can you provide an example of an array_filter solution with that array structure?

Comment: That query analog in php is  echo array_sum(array_intersect_key($table['spend'], array_flip(array_intersect(array_keys($table['status'], 'active'), array_keys($table['plan'], 'weekly')))); but you have to convert the number format to 19000. Or add more function :)

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any native functions to do what you want. What's wrong with storing the information from the CSV files into a database?

If that's simply not an option then try `foreach` loops, they're much cleaner.

```
$spend = array();
foreach ($table['spend'] as $key => $amount)
{
    if ($table['status'][$key] == 'active' && $table['plan'][$key] == 'weekly')
    {
        $spend[] = $amount;
    }
}
```

Whilst it doesn't solve the loops issue it does help clean them up so you don't lose your mind so much.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array Keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get all "active" keys, then loop through only those to find the matches.

```
$keys = array_keys($table['status'], 'active');

foreach($keys as $key)
{
    if($table['plan'][$key] == 'weekly')
    {
        $spend[] = $table['spend'][$key];
    }
}
print_r($spend);
```

Spend:
    Array
    (
        [0] => 19,000
    )

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty messy but I found one way of doing it

```
$keys = array_intersect(array_keys($table['status'], 'active'), array_keys($table['plan'], 'weekly'));
$subs['total'] = array_intersect_key($table['spend'], array_flip($keys));

print_r(array_sum($subs['total']));
```